# Remove unwanted extra gap before first box in flexbox layout

Tags: css, flexbox

I am creating a calendar layout using flexbox. I am getting an extra gap before my first box:

[image: Gap before first element in flexbox]

Below is my code. Could anyone suggest what is creating this additional gap and how I can remove it?

Thank you in advance.

---

```
html {
  font-size: 62, 5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,::before, ::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

header.header-news {
    & > button {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        height: 100%;
        opacity: .5;
     &.last {
       right: 0;
     }   

    }
    & > div.header-news_container {
        display: flex;
    }
    & > div {
        flex: 1 0 0;
    }
  min-height: 18rem;
  position: relative;
}

section.main-content {
  padding-top: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

.main-content__day {
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  width: calc(100% /7 - 1rem);
  display:flex;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .5s;
}
```

Comment: You can use `margin` on the first box, to create a gap.

Comment: Could you please add your HTML, too? And please attach the picture which you mentioned.

Comment: Can you also show the markup you're working with? Please refer to the guide on how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @Anton I think OP wants to remove the extraneous gap before the first element... not to add one.

Comment: @Terry exactly I tried to attach picture. There is a small extra gap before day 1.

Comment: @Maz The picture, this is good. But, it's better when see `html` as well.  You can to read about the `minimal reproducible exaple` above in **Terry's** comment. This means, if someone wants to reproduce your code, will see your problem.